# Query not IQueryable by functions

Tags: c#, linq

Because of `Subtract`, the `filterDevDetailDrillDownModels` makes itself not `IQueryable`.

How can I call functions and still be queryable?

```
var filterDevDetailDrillDownModels
    = filtersQuery.Select(x => new FilterDevDetailDrillDownModel
      {
          FilterIdNew =  x.ID,
          Filter = x.ALNumber,
          Site = x.ALFiltersTech.FirstOrDefault().dic_AL_Sites.Site_Name,
          StartDevDate = (x.FilterMilestones.FirstOrDefault.date.Subtract(DateTime.Now).days......
```

Comment: What would you "query" here? You have a static value type as the result.

Comment: hi michael i need it to be queriable for export

Comment: less edit more answer common!

Comment: You want this to be executed against a DB using Entity Framework? Or what is the issue you have?

Comment: There seems to be an error in your design. This returns a plain class, and that's the way it should be. Where do you think should `IQueryable` (if that's what you talk about) come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because of Substract, the filterDevDetailDrillDownModels makes itself
>   not IQueryable.

I assume you mean the EF data provider cannot translate your query to SQL because of `DateTime.Substract`. Try using [`SqlFunctions.DateDiff`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).